# Concat grouped values after sorting and filtering

Tags: ramda.js

I created a two level deep object in Ramda with `groupBy` statements, which I then used to `sort` and `filter` on.  I now want to concatenate these arrays back into one and return that as the result of a `pipe`.

I have one method, but it feels really over the top for what I want to do.

Example of data:

```
{
    "test1": {
        "123": [
            {
                param1: "test1",
                param2: 123,
            }
        ]
    },
    "test2": {
        "456": [
            {
                param1: "test2",
                param2: 456,
            }
        ]
    },
    "test3": {
        "789": [
            {
                param1: "test3",
                param2: 789,
            },
            {
                param1: "test4",
                param2: 246,
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like the end result of the pipe to be:

```
[
  {
    param1: "test1",
    param2: 123,
  },
  {
    param1: "test2",
    param2: 456,
  },
  {
    param1: "test3",
    param2: 789,
  },
  {
    param1: "test4",
    param2: 246,
  }
]
```

Way I have tried to get it back to an array of objects:

```
pipe(
  ...
  toPairs,
  map(tail),
  flatten,
  map(toPairs),
  map(map(tail)),
  flatten,
)(data)
```

It feels like something like this shouldn't be this difficult.  Any other suggestions on how I can do this?

=============EDIT=============

I also tried this:

```
pipe(
  ...
  map(values),
  values,
  flatten
)(data)
```

Which is a little shorter, but still not sure if it is as elegant as it can be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything more elegant than your updated suggestion.  (Interestingly, without looking at yours, I came up with the same thing, except that I switched `values` and `map(values)` -- it works either way.)

I am curious, though, as to the underlying problem where you needed to do `groupBy` and then flatten the results.  What does it do?  I often use `groupBy` followed by `values`, but I don't think I've ever seen a requirement quite like yours.  What's it for, if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: The data is quite messy banking data from a legacy system (which is being deprecated - thankfully), which never checked referential integrity.

So the same user might have duplicate entries where the bank codes and bank account numbers are the same, but the account type is different.
Dependent on different types of logic only one of these duplicates should be selected.

It made sense to group by bank code, then account number and lastly apply filtering and sorting logic on these subsets.  At the end all the data has to flattened back into in array again.

Comment: Ok, I certainly deal with messy data often enough.  And yes, `groupBy` followed by `map(filter)` or some other massaging, then by `flatten` makes sense.  I should have realized that there would be some intermediate step.